# Sending an array in a javascript function with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is the situation, im creating a clickable dynamic table by adding row with a button. Each row have informations and can be clicked (the entire row). I look for a way to send the information of the row I clicked to another js function who will copie the row in another dynamic table. But here is the trick : to create a clickable row, I use the function `.append` and I create the row in a < a> tag which will use `href="function_to_add_the_copied_row`" to call the other function.

The problem is I cant find out the good syntax. Any suggestion for syntax or other way to do the trick would be appreciated. Here is my code :

```
//javascript function to make clickable rows
{
    var infos = modules_found[i].split("\\t");
            rowNum++;
            //word ="'Row number : "+infos[0]+"'";
            $(".targets").append('<li> <a href="javascript:transferArray(\"'+String(infos[0])+'\")"><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">'+infos[0]+'</div><div class="ui-block-b">'+infos[1]+'</div><div class="ui-block-c">'+infos[2]+'</div></div><div class="ui-block-b ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">'+infos[3]+'</div><div class="ui-block-b">'+infos[4]+'</div><div class="ui-block-c">'+infos[5]+'</div></div></div></a></li>');
}

//javascript function who receive the array and add the copied row
function transferArray(infos)
{
    alert("in transferArray function");
    $(".copied").append('<li> <a href="javascript:alert(\"'+row+'\")"><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">'+infos[0]+'</div><div class="ui-block-b">'+infos[1]+'</div><div class="ui-block-c">'+infos[2]+'</div></div><div class="ui-block-b ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">'+infos[3]+'</div><div class="ui-block-b">'+infos[4]+'</div><div class="ui-block-c">'+infos[5]+'</div></div></div></a></li>');
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working sample here? jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

typically how this is handled - if you are not using some type of javascript library like Angular or Knockout is to just store data in the actual HTML with data attributes.  you can make as many data attributes as you want as long as they start with `data-`

ex.

```
$(".targets").append('<li data-id="xx" data-name="xx" data-custom=""> <a href="...
```

then I would recommend using jQuery click handler on every row by giving them all a class , ex.

```
 $(".targets").append('<li class="rowClick" data-id="xx" data-name="xx" data-custom=""> <a href="...
```

then handle the click like this

```
$(document).on('click' , 'rowClick' , function(e){
     var $this = $(this);
     //get data of row clicked
     var idClicked = $this.attr('data-id');
     var nameClicked = $this.attr('data-name');

     // you also have the full HTML of the clicked row if you need to copy somewhere
     var rowHtml =  $(".copied").append($this);
});
```

You're already using jQuery , so use it to handle the click and then you have the element clicked as a jQuery object right there .  You can use native javascript function to handle the click and pass data like you were , but you already are using jQuery and that will automatically bring in a lot more data for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just a little precision... The $(document) code need to be in the js function, in js file or html file?

Comment: you can put javascript wherever you want , as long as the js file is properly referenced in the HTML

Comment: I tried to simply put an alert in the click event to see if it works, and it seems like the event isn't called. Do you think the fact of leaving the < a> tag empty block the event? I tested without the < a> tag, the row doesn't appear clickable anymore and the click event isn't called either.

Comment: no...... don't leave it empty ,  I was just showing you how to start the HTML ,  finish it with your old code

Comment: I added ... so you can see

Comment: I tried to use $(document).on('click' , 'rowClick' , function(e){}); , but it seems like its never called. Could the < a> tag take the priority and take the control of the click event?

Comment: make sure there is nothing in href of the a tag , also make sure you added the class rowClick to the li element

Answer (score 1):

Here is a high level approach (assuming you know jQuery): instead of wrapping your row inside A tag, better way is to have register a click event listener on your table (via jQuery APIs and not in HTML). In that click handler you can get the index of row clicked easily (make use of jQuery APIs) and once you have the rowindex, you can easily clone the row and move it to somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately I started html/css/js/php 2 weeks ago... (c++/c# guy thrown in web programming =S) But thanks for the answer!

Comment: welcome to the JS world! I recommend these books for JS (in general for core JS concepts) - https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used native javascript function since the suggested solution didn't work, even if it looks all legit. So here is what I have done:

```
   (...)
//append the js function
$(".FindTable").append('<li id="addedFindRow"><a href="javascript:copyrow(\''+infos[0]+'\',\''+infos[1]+'\',\''+infos[2]+'\',\''+infos[3]+'\',\''+infos[4]+'\',\''+infos[5]+'\');"><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">'+infos[0]+'</div><div class="ui-block-b">'+infos[1]+'</div><div class="ui-block-c">'+infos[2]+'</div></div><div class="ui-block-b ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a">'+infos[3]+'</div><div class="ui-block-b">'+infos[4]+'</div><div class="ui-block-c">'+infos[5]+'</div></div></div></a></li>');
}

function copyrow(info0,info1,info2,info3,info4,info5)
{
    //use data
}
```

This is quite heavy, but that will do. Would be more chaotic if there was more parameters thought.